# SeekBar setProgress() in onCreate

Tags: android, restore, seekbar, oncreate

I have a question about setting the progress of a SeekBar in onCreate.
First of all a minimum working example:
**the layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**And here the activity:**
When the app is started -> seekBar is max (OK)
When screen is rotated -> seekBar should be min (only OK if android:saveEnabled="false")

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        if (savedInstanceState == null)
            seekBar.setProgress(seekBar.getMax());
        else {
            seekBar.setProgress(0);

            editText.setText("myText");
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "progress: " + seekBar.getProgress() + "\ttext: " + editText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            }
        });
    }

    public void buttonClicked(View view) {
        SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        seekBar.setProgress(0);
        editText.setText("myText");
    }
}
```

**Edit2**
What the toast shows:
1st onCreate: progress 100 text: 
2nd onCreate: progress 0 text: myText

But what the sceen shows:
1st onCreate: progress 100 text: 
2nd onCreate: progress 100 text: 
**/Edit2**

It seems to me that the progress-value (0 in this case) that should be set after a restore is overriden but I can't imagine why.
**Edit**
It is clear to me that super.onCreate() restores the saved state (the progress that is automatically saved before destroying the activity, max if the bar wasn't changed or any other value the bar was changed to by the user) of the seekBar with its previous progess but setting the new progress-value is done **after** that.

Can anybody explain this behavior (especially why setProgress() after restoring with super.onCreate does not work if android:saveEnabled="true" is set)?
**/Edit**

Comment: Why do you pass `null` to `super.onCreate`?

Comment: Sorry that was for testing - forgot to change it back but edited it already!

Comment: Have you tried to overwrite `onSaveInstanceState`? Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)

Comment: when you say previous progress you mean it comes back with the max value? if so that is not the previous progress because you set it to max, like @codemonkey say's you need to override that and save anything and your current oncreate code will check out good

Comment: When onCreate is called the first time the progress is set to max (as it should) but on every other call the progress is set to the state saved automatically (max if the bar wasn't changed or the value it was changed to before destroying it) but it is NOT set to 0. I don't understand why the saved progress isn't overriden because the call to set the progress is after restoring the state.

Comment: @michi099 The point is: You don't restore anything in your example. You have to overwrite `onSaveInstanceState` for that. Have you read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html)?

Comment: Yes I read the documentation. The problem is that I don't understand why I can't update the restored view! So when the activity is destroyed android saves all my views with an ID and when the activity is recreated onCreate can access those saved views stored in the Bundle. Because of that the seekBar's progress is set to the progress it had before the activity was destroyed. I really don't understand why I can't set the progress in onCreate to a new value but if I create for example an onClick-handler the progress can be updated when the seekBar is clicked!

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the line `seekBar.setProgress(0);` and check if the debugger stops there. I bet that the program never executes this line.

Comment: It must execute this line - I have a nice example! If I make a Toast with a seekBar.getProgress() it shows 0 after I rotate the screen but only the seekBar is shown as if it was max!

Comment: What I found out now:
The new progess (0) is set correctly IN onCreate but the progress is restored AFTER executing my overriden onCreate method. So I update the seekBar in onCreate and my value get overwritten. When I click the button after rotating the screen seekBar.getProgress shows 100 although the toast in onCreate showed 0!